QueryDisplayConfig/SetDisplayConfig APIs set resolution failed
When using the QueryDisplayConfig/SetDisplayedConfig APIs to modify screen resolution, regardless of the operation, the code 87 is returned. I cannot know what caused it. I used the method of VNet DisplayedConfig Buffer Sizes, but I still failed
[Image]: https://i.sstatic.net/gY0OfDlI.png
Here is my complete code：
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    // Structure definition
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO
    {
        public uint pathId;
        public uint sourceMode;
        public uint targetMode;
        public uint statusFlags;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO
    {
        public uint width;
        public uint height;
        public uint refreshRate;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO_V2
    {
        public uint pathId;
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO sourceMode;
        public DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO targetMode;
        public uint statusFlags;
    }

    // API
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(uint pathInfoCount, uint modeInfoCount, ref uint pathInfoSize, ref uint modeInfoSize);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int QueryDisplayConfig(uint flags, ref uint pathInfoSize, IntPtr pathInfo, ref uint modeInfoSize, IntPtr modeInfo, IntPtr currentSettings);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int SetDisplayConfig(uint flags, uint pathInfoCount, IntPtr pathInfo, uint modeInfoCount, IntPtr modeInfo, uint currentSettings);

    const uint SDC_TOPOLOGY_CLONE = 0x00000001;
    const uint SDC_TOPOLOGY_EXTEND = 0x00000002;
    const uint SDC_TOPOLOGY_INTERNAL = 0x00000004;

    // log
   private static void Log(string message)
    {
        string logMessage = $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - {message}";
        Console.WriteLine(logMessage);

        // Optionally log to a file
        try
        {
            string logFile = "screen_resolution_change.log";
            File.AppendAllText(logFile, logMessage + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error writing to log file: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

   public static void Main()
    {
        uint pathInfoSize = 0;
        uint modeInfoSize = 0;

        // Get buffer size
        Log("Getting buffer sizes for display configuration...");
        int result = GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(0, 0, ref pathInfoSize, ref modeInfoSize);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            Log($"Error in GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes: {result}");
            return;
        }

        Log($"Buffer sizes - PathInfoSize: {pathInfoSize}, ModeInfoSize: {modeInfoSize}");

        // Allocate memory for path information and mode information
        IntPtr pathInfoBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)pathInfoSize);
        IntPtr modeInfoBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)modeInfoSize);

        try
        {
            // Query display configuration
            Log("Querying current display configuration...");
            result = QueryDisplayConfig(0, ref pathInfoSize, pathInfoBuffer, ref modeInfoSize, modeInfoBuffer, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (result != 0)
            {
                Log($"Error in QueryDisplayConfig: {result}");
                return;
            }

            Log("Current display configuration retrieved successfully.");

            // Obtain and modify resolution
            DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO_V2 pathInfo = Marshal.PtrToStructure<DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO_V2>(pathInfoBuffer);
            DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO newMode = pathInfo.sourceMode;
            newMode.width = 1920; // New resolution width
            newMode.height = 1080; // New resolution height

            // Output the modified resolution
            Log($"Changing resolution to {newMode.width}x{newMode.height}");

            // Modify display settings
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(newMode, modeInfoBuffer, false);

            // Apply new display configuration
            Log("Applying new display configuration...");
            result = SetDisplayConfig(0, 1, pathInfoBuffer, 1, modeInfoBuffer, 0);
            if (result != 0)
            {
                Log($"Error in SetDisplayConfig: {result}");
            }
            else
            {
                Log("Resolution changed successfully!");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // free memory
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pathInfoBuffer);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(modeInfoBuffer);
        }
    }
}


87 is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER - so check your parameters

Sir, What parameters should I pass in during the first call？

You have to call the method GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes first to determine the length of both arrays. After that you can call the method QueryDisplayConfig.
Here a complete example how to call that Win32 methods

Add the nuget package Microsoft.Windows.CsWin32 to your project

Add a file named NativeMethods.txt in the root path of your project with the following content
GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes
QueryDisplayConfig


Finally the code to call both methods
using System.ComponentModel;

using Windows.Win32;
using Windows.Win32.Devices.Display;
using Windows.Win32.Foundation;

QUERY_DISPLAY_CONFIG_FLAGS flags = QUERY_DISPLAY_CONFIG_FLAGS.QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS;

CheckWin32Error( PInvoke.GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes( flags,
    out uint numInfoPathArrayElements,
    out uint numInfoModesArrayElements ) );

DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[] infoPaths = new DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[numInfoPathArrayElements];
DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[] infoModes = new DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[numInfoModesArrayElements];

unsafe
{
    DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID* currentTopologyId = null;

    fixed ( DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO* pInfoPaths = infoPaths )
    fixed ( DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO* pInfoModes = infoModes )
    {
        CheckWin32Error( PInvoke.QueryDisplayConfig( flags,
            ref numInfoPathArrayElements,
            pInfoPaths, ref numInfoModesArrayElements, pInfoModes, currentTopologyId ) );
    }
}

// now handle the data in infoPaths and infoModes

return;

static void CheckWin32Error( WIN32_ERROR result )
{
    if ( result == WIN32_ERROR.NO_ERROR )
    {
        return;
    }

    throw new Win32Exception( (int)result );
}




Sir, could you please take a look at my complete code? I have listened to your suggestion and first called the method of GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(), but it still returned the error code 87. I don't know where the problem lies.

You have to read the documentation. GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes has three params and you assume it has four. Also you misunderstood the first param in both calls. Check the docs and compare your code with mine as I gave you a fully working example

Sir, thank you for your guidance. Can you guide me on how to use SetDisplayedConfig? I have successfully added it to NativeMethods.txt, but I encountered some difficulties while using it. I am unable to modify my resolution.

In fact, when I call the SetDisplay Config method, the returned value is still 87
